# Enable a Coming Soon Page while the rest of the site is accessible

Tags: plugins, maintenance

I am working on a feature that will be available in the future.

How can I create a coming soon page while leaving the rest of the page accessible by visitors?

Comment: explained in a different way, you want to change temporarily the home page ?

Answer (score 0):

you can try WP Maintenance Mode plugin
also check this link https://www.sourcewp.com/best-wordpress-maintenance-mode-plugins/

Comment: This is not what I wanted. Because visitors cannot access homepage when this plugin is enabled.